# Model->find() conditions with no associated results

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

To stay simple, I have a User model which hasMany Post.

```
[User] id
[Post] id, user_id
```

How can I write a `$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)` to get all User who has no Post ?

Comment: Start with an sql query that returns just that (e.g. `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`) unless/until you know the sql you want to generate, you won't be able to write the CakePHP code to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one function inside User model and try below code: It will give all the User.id having no posts.

```
$options = array(
        'conditions'=>array('Post.id is NULL')
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'Post',  
                'table' => ‘posts’,
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Post.user_id = User.id',
                ),
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array('User.id')
    );

 $returnData = $this->find('list',$options);
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming Post belongsTo User:

```
$this->User->Post->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'fields' => array('User.id', 'user_id', 'COUNT(user_id) AS posts_count'),
        'group' => 'user_id HAVING posts_count = 0'
    )
)
```